# Did Florida manage a better COVID death rate than the US average despite strong resistance to prevention measures?

Tags: united-states, covid-19

I was reading about [Ron Desantis on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_DeSantis#cite_note-125) and was a little surprised by the section about his handling of COVID-19 in Florida.  It lists a huge number of actions to oppose standard COVID preventative measures, including outlawing mask and vaccine mandates and minimal shutdowns of the state.  It also claims that Florida had some of the highest death tolls in later parts of the epidemic.

However it also has these two statements:

> Florida's death rate from COVID-19 (75,000 deaths) ended up being within the national average and Florida's economy fared better than many other U.S. states

and

> in May 2022, a Bloomberg News op-ed claimed that, when adjusting state death tolls based on what they would be if age distribution were equal between the states, Florida's COVID-19 death toll would be less than the national average

I'm skeptical that Florida could average better than the national average while resisting all precautions.  A quick search found [Statistica.com](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1109011/coronavirus-covid19-death-rates-us-by-state/) which lists Florida's current per capita death toll as of this month as the 14th highest in the USA, with a death rate of 426/100,000.  By contrast the [John Hopkin's Coronavirus Resource Center](https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/data/mortality) shows the current average death rate for USA as 329.68/100,000, which would seem to refute at least the first claim I quoted, unless there are differences in how death rate or average is being measured.

The one potential discrepancy I could see is that the Wikipedia links are a bit older, so Florida may have caught up/exceeded the national average since then as it's still a hotspot for COVID as I understand?  But it's hard to believe a few months could make that huge a difference in numbers.

So, is Wikipedia's claim that Florida managed as well, or better, then the national average true at the time the links were cited, and is it still true now?

Comment: Here's [the same opinion piece on WaPo](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/california-versus-florida-a-covid-reckoning/2022/05/07/6e37a27c-ce06-11ec-b7ee-74f09d827ca6_story.html) with no paywall.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## The source provides no methodology.

***tl;dr*** The claim that "if age distribution were equal" is not complete. The original source adjusts COVID mortality by age and an ill-defined "metabolic health". They provide no methodology for either. Without knowing the details, they could have done any amount of monkeying with the numbers.

The results are meaningless.

## The Britannica Claim

> Florida's death rate from COVID-19 (75,000 deaths) ended up being within the national average and Florida's economy fared better than many other U.S. states.

This is from a [Britannica article about Ron DeSantis](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Ron-DeSantis) and provides no citations how they concluded Florida is within the national average.

## The Bloomberg Claim

> in May 2022, a Bloomberg News op-ed claimed that, when adjusting state death tolls based on what they would be if age distribution were equal between the states, Florida's COVID-19 death toll would be less than the national average

This is from an op-ed by Justin Fox. He is a Bloomberg Opinion columnist covering business, not health. [The same op-ed was posted in the Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/california-versus-florida-a-covid-reckoning/2022/05/07/6e37a27c-ce06-11ec-b7ee-74f09d827ca6_story.html) with no paywall.

### Hiding inequality in averages

The relevant claim appears to be this:

> Adjust state Covid mortality statistics to what they would be if all the states’ populations had roughly the same age distribution as the nation — as conservative activist and policy analyst Phil Kerpen has been doing for much of the pandemic — and Florida’s rate drops to 275 per 100,000, well below the national rate of 302, while California’s rises to 267.

Phil Kerpen is a founder of the Committee To Unleash Prosperity. More on them in a moment.

We must address whether ignoring a state's demographics is a relevant statistic. It smacks of the ["sacrifice the elderly"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/47989/38242) modest proposals of the early pandemic.

Population demographics are not a hypothetical. Those are real people, really getting sick, and really dying. Instead of arguing that Florida would have done better with average demographics, one can argue Florida failed to adapt their policies to their population.

It's very tempting to boil everything down into a single number for the "average person", but there is no such thing as an average person. Populations are messy. For example, (50, 50, 50, 50) and (-100, 100, 200, 0) are very different sets of numbers, but they average (mean) out the same. Abusing population averages is a way to hide inequalities.

I would argue that if we really want to compare states without being biased by their age distributions, we shouldn't be mashing all ages together into one statistic. We should be looking at COVID mortality rates by age. This removes the age distribution bias without artificially smoothing out bumps. We should compare people apples-to-apples, not applesauce-to-applesauce.

That's just what this chart already does (sorry about the poor quality)...

[image]

...we can see that, relative to California, Florida did as good or slightly better with their 75+ population. However, they did far worse with their younger populations. That is more meaningful information than one number for all ages.

One could argue that doing worse in younger populations is less relevant because their death rates are orders of magnitude lower than the 75+ rates, but this all teeters on the verge of devaluing lives. Devaluing the elderly by ignoring the demographic differences and devaluing the young by ignoring their higher death rates in Florida.

### *A Final Report Card on the States’ Response to COVID-19*

This claim appears to be sourced from [A Final Report Card on the States’ Response to COVID-19](https://committeetounleashprosperity.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Which-States-Handled-the-Covid-Pandemic-Best.pdf) by Phil Kerpen, Stephen Moore and [Casey Mulligan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casey_B._Mulligan) of the [Committee To Unleash Prosperity](https://committeetounleashprosperity.com/). The numbers don't exactly agree, maybe they were using an earlier version, but they are very close.

The Committee To Unleash Prosperity is an organization to [promote supply side economics](https://committeetounleashprosperity.com/about/). They are [anti-regulation](https://committeetounleashprosperity.com/services/repeal-onerous-regulations/). Its founders are all economists, not public health professionals. All the authors of the paper are economists, not public health professionals.

Critically, there's little discussion of their methodology; no formulas are provided. However, while the article only mentions age, the report also includes "metabolic health"...

> We adjust COVID mortality (through March 5, 2022) for ***age and “metabolic health,”*** by which we mean the pre-pandemic prevalence of obesity and diabetes – as these are highly correlated with higher death
> rates from the virus.

There is no methodology about how they calculated or applied "metabolic health". How did they determine the prevalence? How did it affect the COVID mortality rate? Why only obesity and diabetes? Why not respiratory problems? Auto-immune diseases? Without that information, we can't check their math; their adjusted COVID mortality rates are meaningless. They could have used it as a fudge factor, tweaking the method until they got the result they wanted.

With all this in mind, and the lack of methodology, the source cannot be used.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141473/discussion-on-answer-by-schwern-did-florida-manage-a-better-covid-death-rate-tha).

Answer (score 14):

> Florida's economy fared better than many other U.S. states

No one addressed the economic angle, so I'll take a stab. The best source of economic performance in each state is the Bureau of Economic Analysis. If we evaluate the [annualized change in GDP](https://apps.bea.gov/itable/index.html?appid=70&stepnum=40&Major_Area=3&State=0&Area=XX&TableId=532&Statistic=1&Year=2019:Q4&YearBegin=2019:Q4&Year_End=2022:Q2&Unit_Of_Measure=AAGR&Rank=1&Drill=1&nRange=5&AppId=70) between Q4 2019 and Q2 2022, we get the following results:

- US as a whole: +1.4%
- Florida: +3.5%, ranked #4 among the 50 states
- Mississippi (had the [highest COVID death rate per capita](https://www.statista.com/statistics/1109011/coronavirus-covid19-death-rates-us-by-state/)): +0.8%, ranked #35
- Hawaii (lowest death rate per capita): -2.3%, ranked #45
- Vermont (second lowest death rate): +1.6%, ranked #19

Economically speaking Florida is the 4th best performing state in the country, so that part of the claim is definitely true. The three states ahead of Florida (Idaho, Tennessee, Utah) were also notable for having relatively lax COVID regulations.

**Update**: it was suggested in the comments that historical patterns matter, because it's possible that Florida was already growing very rapidly before the pandemic. Looking at the annualized change in GDP [between Q2 2017 and Q4 2019](https://apps.bea.gov/itable/index.html?appid=70&stepnum=40&Major_Area=3&State=0&Area=XX&TableId=532&Statistic=1&Year=2019:Q4&YearBegin=2017:Q2&Year_End=2019:Q4&Unit_Of_Measure=AAGR&Rank=1&Drill=1&nRange=5&AppId=70) we see the following data:

- US as a whole: +2.7%
- Florida: +3.0%, ranked #15 among the 50 states
- Mississippi: +0.6%, ranked #46
- Hawaii: +0.4%, ranked #49
- Vermont: +0.9%, ranked #40

So Florida went from #15 to #4 in the ranking of fastest growing states. So it becomes clear that Florida really did do great economically, even compared to its previous growth.

Comment: How does that compare to non-Covid years? It's hard to interpret the numbers without knowing if in other years they had a GDP growth of about the same, more, or even less.

Comment: @Laurel past performance is no guarantee of future results. We can't just extrapolate pre-COVID growth rates and pretend like they would've continued forever.

Comment: It might not be a guarantee of future results but if Florida typically ranks in the top for growth then saying it ranked in the top for growth during covid doesn't mean as much.

Comment: @JoeW For growth over 2016-2019 it ranked at #11, so moving up to #4 is an improvement. If Covid deaths had any influence whatsoever, it’s too small to notice in the data.

Comment: That would be good information to include in the answer as it shows how they compared to other states in the past. Though it can be said that still puts them as doing better then most other states normally.

Comment: This is totally out of any context with the pandemic.  The pandemic did not strike all states equally or at the same time.  I also wonder if this is impacted by using RDP values which includes personal income.  For a state like Florida with a high number of wealthy, retired people it's likely less volatile other states.

Comment: @MikeJ lots of people were claiming in 2020 that locking down harder is also good for the economy. I’ve yet to see any proof that this was the case in the long term. If you’ve got better numbers please add your own answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez, I'm not claiming locking down harder is better, I'm saying using the numbers that you did does not make the argument that you're claiming it does.

Comment: @Laurel updated with some pre-COVID data which actually makes Florida look even better

Comment: @JonathanReez, you can't make the argument you're making with this data. There are too many holes in it.  First it's not GDP it's RGDP which includes personal income data that may not have been affected by the pandemic given the high number of retires.  But more importantly you cannot treat the pandemic as something that affected all states the same. It just didn't.

Comment: @MikeJ The post made just one claim about the economy: *Florida's economy fared better than many other U.S. states*. My numbers prove that this is true. For other claims please start a separate Skeptics question.

Comment: @JonathanReez, your numbers do not prove that's true.  Your numbers don't support your argument.  There are too many other factors.

Comment: @MikeJ But you’re also right that Florida’s anti lockdown stance attracted a lot of internal migration and capital from pro-lockdown states. Migration from California was particularly notable. So Florida benefitted from both refusing to lockdown and from people fleeing unfriendly regimes in other states.

Comment: @JonathanReez, actually Florida benefited from 6 billion in federal aid, it benefited in having it's tax revenue derived from consumption taxes which shot up with the trillion dollar bailout that put most of that trillion into pandemic payments to individuals who then turned around and got taxed on it by Florida. Again the picture is more complicated than you're making it out to be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141439/discussion-between-jonathanreez-and-mikej).

Answer (score 13):

I had enough comments that they ended up forming a supplementary answer on their own.

> So, is Wikipedia's claim that Florida managed as well, or better, then the national average true at the time the links were cited, and is it still true now?

So, to start, it should be noted that the article claimed "within the national average", not "below", so when you state earlier on:

> I'm skeptical that Florida could average better than the national average while resisting all precautions.

you're skeptical of a claim the source does not make.

We can try to verify its position relative to the national average by narrowing the dates. The Brittanica source's own article history shows that that claim was in an article posted on 31 August 2022. The same claim about being "within the average" notes that Florida had had "more than 75,000 [deaths]", and checking [a chart of total deaths over time in Florida](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/usa/florida/), the first time it had registered >75K deaths was 02 June 2022. That means that the "within the national average" claim would be based on stats from between 02 June and 31 August of 2022.

Using 2022 population figures of 22.1M for Florida and 338.3M for the whole of the U.S., and the same cumulative deaths source, Florida began that period with 75,016 deaths (339.4 deaths/100K), and ended on 31 Aug with 80,446 (364.0 deaths/100K). The U.S. as a whole grew from 1,036,634 deaths (306.4 deaths/100K) to 1,074,162 (317.5 deaths/100K). **Florida's per-capita death toll was 10.8% higher than the U.S. average at the beginning of the window, and grew to 14.6% higher by the end of the window (likely due, at least in part, to Florida's choice to limit mitigations; at least today it's slightly more vaccinated than the U.S. average, at 69% fully vaccinated to the U.S. average of 68%).** This doesn't put it outside a single standard deviation from the mean for "worst states", so it could be said to be "within the national average", but it was by no means "below average" at any point when that data could have been collected, and was definitely a non-trivial amount above average.

At the time I'm writing this, it has [the 14th highest total per-capita death rate](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html) (out of 56; the 50 U.S. states, D.C. and the five U.S. territories with meaningful population). It was probably a little better back in the summer (it's had a persistently higher death rate than the average for a while), but still nowhere near *below* average. The most recent numbers for 15 Dec 2022 from [the same source for the cumulative deaths over time number](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/usa/florida/) are larger, but the percentage gap between Florida and the U.S. is largely unchanged (still rounds to 14.6%, though [NYT's data](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html) shows a greater gap, 387 vs. 330, 17.3% higher for Florida than the U.S.) so the accuracy now is not meaningfully different than it was at the latest possible data the claim could have based its claim on.

As others have already noted, Bloomberg's op-ed provides no methodology for their adjustments, so it's impossible to verify, and given the source, it's suspicious. On age alone, Florida is one of the oldest states:

[image: Florida is one of the oldest states]

but of the four states with older populations (from the map, WV, VT, NH and ME), only one has a higher per-capita COVID death toll (WV, with a *much* worse vaccination rate of 59%) and three of them have *significantly* lower death tolls (VT, NH and ME, with per-capita death rates 125, 209 and 208 respectively) ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-cases.html)). While VT and ME have *much* higher vaccination rates than Florida, NH is comparable to Florida (at 70% to Florida's 69%), so Florida merely having an older population is not sufficient to explain their worse performance.

Answer (score 1):

According to reports in the media, Florida changed the way that deaths were reported to reduce the headline mortality rate.

> The *Miami Herald* found that until three weeks ago, information gathered by DOH counted deaths by the date they were recorded. But on August 10, the state switched to tallying new deaths by the date an individual died, which can cause a lag in reporting because those deaths need to be evaluated and certificates need to be processed first.

[Florida's New COVID Reporting Method Shows 'Artificial Decline' in Latest Data](https://www.newsweek.com/floridas-new-covid-reporting-method-shows-artificial-decline-latest-data-1624657)

Comment: The change seems for the better and shouldn’t impact the overall numbers.

Comment: @JonathanReez, the changes included removing people whos deaths were handled out of state, even if they occurred in state.

Comment: It might be helpful to add that last fact to your answer.

Comment: @JonathanReez: The other issue the change could cause (besides the change excluding some deaths) is that, given people continue to die at meaningful rates, any comparison at a fixed point in time of reported deaths, where the other population being compared does *not* delay reporting, will favor Florida. The slant towards Florida asymptotically approaches zero (the delayed deaths become a smaller fraction of the total), but it matters; Florida has been around 24-30 deaths/day recently, so if the lag is 30 days, they'll exclude 720-900 deaths (~1% of their total deaths to date).

Comment: @ShadowRanger cool but we’re so far into the pandemic now that it’s a negligible difference (1% as per your own calculation)

Comment: @JonathanReez: While reducing Florida's apparent per-capita death toll by 1% wouldn't make a big difference to the rankings today, when they made the change, it was the peak of the Delta wave; even with the change in reporting they lost ~18.5K in August and September 2021 (jumping from 39,998 dead on July 31 to 58,564 on Sept. 30). A one month lag would reduce their apparent death toll by ~16% back then, a *huge* difference. For summer '22 (when claim made, and death rate higher than today), it was only a 2.3% effect, but still enough to bump it from 14th to 12th highest deaths today.

Comment: Mind you, I have no idea how much of a relative delay the changes imposed, and how much the cumulative effect of removing in-state deaths handled out-of-state from the peak of Delta through the present would affect Florida's numbers, but it's fairly clear the change in reporting both lowered their ongoing reported deaths *and* made them appear even better if you compared their numbers to-date (and even comparing historical numbers, depending on whether the delayed reporting changed the date the death was claimed to occur, vs. retroactively updating the toll for the actual day of death).

Comment: @ShadowRanger ok how is that relevant as an answer *today* for the Skeptics question asked?

Comment: @JonathanReez: 1) Today isn't what matters; the claim being dissected dates from summer of 2022, so that's what matters. 2) At that time, the delay benefited Florida by potentially keeping them a few places lower in the death toll rankings (it'd be harder to argue that being in the top 10 for deaths is "within the national average"). 3) Add that to the fact that they've apparently been concealing deaths since the peak of Delta, meaning nearly a year of deaths, a year with a *heavy* death toll, went underreported, and it's meaningful, though not conclusive, in addressing the claim.

Comment: I remember there being some controversy about Florida's mortality data not including people who died in state, but who were officially resident in another state for things like voting or taxes. I don't have a good source for this, maybe someone else can follow up?

Comment: Florida has consistently tried to limit their reported covid death rate. From changing how they report deaths to pausing reporting deaths at all. While DeSantis was calling pandemic reporting as "Media hysteria" Florida was leading the nation in pediatric covid hospitalizations.  Any suggestion that Florida fared better in the Pandemic then other states is completely fantasy.

Comment: @MikeJ, Could we please have a source or some statistics to cover the statement you made about "Florida was leading the nation in pediatric covid hospitalizations."

Comment: @AaarghZombies, google is your friend:  https://www.forbes.com/sites/nicholasreimann/2021/08/03/florida-shatters-record-for-covid-hospitalization-again-as-desantis-downplays-crisis/?sh=7077a1485884 it was widely reported.   How about Ron settling lawsuit about hiding covid data: https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2023/oct/15/ron-desantis-republican-presidential-campaign-covid-data-florida-deaths  Florida is a disaster

Comment: @MikeJ, you're source says that a state with a large population had a large number of sick people, but those numbers as a percentage of the population aren't remarkable. If you look at it per head of population Florida did better with a light lockdown than NYC did with a totalitarian one.

Comment: @AaarghZombies, sigh.  no the link says Florida lead the country in children hospitalized with covid while DeSantis was down playing the disease.  The link says while DeSantis was ordering all public schools to make masks optional Florida was putting more kids in the hospital with Covid than any other state.

Comment: @AaarghZombies, and honestly the whole lock down thing is so mind numbing at this point.  NY was the epicenter of the outbreak on the east coast.  It's been well covered already. You can't compare the two.  https://www.politifact.com/factchecks/2021/feb/26/instagram-posts/chart-comparing-new-york-and-florida-covid-19-flaw/

Comment: @MikeJ, Substitute for London, England. or Paris, or Berlin.

Comment: @MikeJ, the article said a lot of things, what it didn't say was how it reached that conclusion. Florida's demographic meant that this was inevitable, not it's political policies. Lots of children in air conditioned classroom with the windows closed and no natural ventilation.

Comment: @AaarghZombies https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_of_disbelief  you're working too hard at this.  What it said in that article, and in many others, is that Florida led the nation in kids hospitalized with covid while DeSantis downplayed covid.  https://www.tampabay.com/news/health/2021/08/02/florida-leads-the-nation-in-kids-hospitalized-for-covid/ https://www.floridatrend.com/article/31916/florida-leads-the-nation-in-kids-hospitalized-for-covid https://www.news-journalonline.com/story/news/coronavirus/2021/08/11/florida-has-highest-number-covid-hospitalizations-among-children/5558688001

Comment: @AaarghZombies, you forgot something.. windows closed, no natural ventilation, and the governor of Florida banning mask mandates in schools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151949/discussion-between-aaargh-zombies-and-mikej).